# Return xlsx data in Task<IHttpActionResult> with EPPlus

Tags: excel, api, postman, xlsx, epplus

I have a basic web api that is trying to return an excel document triggered as a download action rather than a data stream.  I have followed many examples online in regards to creating the stream and setting attachment properties but my Postman requests always show as encoded.  Below is the API method.

```
[Route("getexcel")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExcel()
{
   IHttpActionResult result = null;
   FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Test.xlsx");
   ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);

   HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(pck.GetAsByteArray());
   response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
   response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
   response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Test.xlsx";

   result = ResponseMessage(response);
   return result;
}
```

From the code above if I use MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf") then the Postman request shows the request to download but for the xlsx format or application/octet-stream it does not.  Instead it shows a stream of data.  The Content-Type is application/json because the final version of the api will be taking json data in the body.

[image: Postman request]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be late, but...
There is "Send and Download" in dropdown menu on Send button
[image]

Comment: This is the correct solution, I realized this a few days after creating the question and forgot to update so thanks for replying.